# Django Rest Framework: Access item detail by slug instead of ID

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to use a object's slug (or any other field) to access the details of an item, instead of using the ID?

For example, if I have an item with the slug "lorem" and ID 1. By default the URL is `http://localhost:9999/items/1/`. I want to access it via `http://localhost:9999/items/lorem/` instead.

Adding `lookup_field` in the serializer's Meta class did nothing to change the automatically generated URL nor did it allow me to access the item by manually writing the slug instead of the ID in the URL.

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    # An arbitrary, user provided, URL
    item_url = models.URLField(unique=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class ClassItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('url', 'slug', 'title', 'item_url')
```

views.py

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
```

urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'items', views.ItemViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Generated JSON:

```
[
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:9999/items/1/",
        "slug": "lorem",
        "title": "Lorem",
        "item_url": "http://example.com"
    }
]
```

Comment: No time for a full answer, but you may find what you're looking for on the [routers docs page for DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter). Specifically, at the bottom of the linked section for `SimpleRouter`, look at the example with `class MyModelViewSet`. I think that's letting you change the lookup value to whatever you want. May be a good starting point.

Comment: Do note that you're using `DefaultRouter`, not `SimpleRouter`... not sure which this functionality is in both classes.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You should set `lookup_field` in your serializer:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('url', 'slug', 'title', 'item_url')
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }
```

and in your view:

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

I got this result:

```
~ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/testslug/ | python -mjson.tool
{
    "item_url": "https://example.com/", 
    "slug": "testslug", 
    "title": "Test Title", 
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/testslug/"
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to note that with the addition of `extra_kwargs = { 'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'} }`, I received the following error: **TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lookup_field'**. Once I removed that, it worked fine.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, Thanks for you comment. Otherwise I would wasted more time.

Comment: This happened because I was not using 'url' field in the Serializer Meta class fields tuple. After adding 'url' field I has use: extra_kwargs ={'url':{'lookup_field:'slug''}}

Comment: @javed it's true, It also happens that if the fields attribute is a list instead of tuple also does not works. It's great :D

Comment: Note: the `unexpected keyword argument 'lookup_field'` error can also occur if you have a `@property` defined on the model called `url`.

Answer (score 10):

In some scenarios you may want to have both the "low level" `pk` value and the more semantic `slug`. I like to have both options personally and do this by setting the `lookup_field` later in the viewset `as_view()` method in my `urls.py`.

> Note: the following defaults to `pk` with an optional `slug` lookup. To combine this with previous answer you would change the `lookup_field` below to be `"pk"` instead of `"slug".`

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

from myobjects import views as myviews


# simplify the view definitions by splitting out the options
REQDICT = {
    'get': 'retrieve',
    'put': 'update',
    'patch': 'partial_update',
    'delete': 'destroy'
}


# define the pk detail view
myobject_detail = myviews.MyObjectViewset.as_view(REQDICT)
# define the slug detail view
myobject_slug_detail = myviews.MyObjectViewset.as_view(REQDICT, lookup_field='slug')


urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^myobjects/(?P<pk>\d*)/$",
           myobject_detail,
           name = 'myobject-detail'),
    url(r"^myobjects/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$",
           myobject_slug_detail,
           name = 'myobject-slug-detail'),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

> *This could also be in your `views.py` - my preference is to see it beside the `urlpatterns` list*.